# How do I add a new shape to an Existing Shape Group in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, shapes

I need help adding a new shape to an Existing Shape Group. Lets say I created a shapegroup after iterating through all shapes on Activesheet using the following code.

```
Set ShapeGroupX = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range((x)).Group
```

Now if I add a new shape using Activesheet.shapes.AddShape and give it a unique name, how do I add this shape to ShapeGroupX without having to ungroup ShapeGroupX and group again?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. I deleted my answer. AFAIK and I could be wrong but you will have to ungroup and regroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to `Ungroup` followed by `Group`:

```
Sub MakeBigGroup()
    With ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
        .Ungroup
        .Group
     End With
End Sub
```